# which query is efficient and correct to get results based on Highest value from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table 'PlayerStats' which contains following rows

```
Id Runs  HS
 1 536   96
 2 586   98
 3 423   82
```

I have written following (3) queries. which is the best and effiecent in Sql server

Query1

```
select * from PlayerStats order by Runs desc
```

Query2

```
 SELECT *
     FROM
     (SELECT Runs,HS,DENSE_RANK() over(ORDER BY Runs desc) AS rk 
     FROM PlayerStats) as a
```

Query3

```
With empCTE2 as
(
   SELECT Runs,HS,DENSE_RANK() over(ORDER BY Runs desc) as _rank from PlayerStats
)
select * from empCTE2
```

Comment: Some may depend on what SQL (oracle, MS SQL, etc) and indexes on the table, but your first one is the most basic and will do what you want, all the other ways would probably work but are way more complicated, simplest is usually the best

Comment: I am getting same result for all query.

Comment: No you are't. You aren't returning ID in your last two queries (from the sub query) for starters.

Answer (score 1):

Simplicity is the best:

```
select * from PlayerStats order by Runs desc;
-- you should avoid using `*` and you should expand column list to match 
-- 2nd and 3rd
```

If all you need is to sort resultset then use first approach.

Second and third (subquery/CTE) query are virtually the same so there shouldn't be any difference between them. But there is a caveat:

```
SELECT *
FROM(SELECT Runs,HS,DENSE_RANK() over(ORDER BY Runs desc) AS rk 
    FROM PlayerStats) as a
-- there is no ORDER BY on the most outerquery, so the order is not guaranteed
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is enough to handle if just you want to sort all records by runs

Second and third query will be more efficient when you want to get sort by any specific partition.